# LDAP + SSH : How to specify slave LDAP server on clients?

Tags: linux, ssh, ldap

I managed to install mirror mode with 2 LDAP servers. Now I would like to specify these LDAP servers in ldap.conf on clients. What I'm trying to do, that when primary LDAP server is offline, PAM on client should contact slave LDAP. But it does not work.

URI ldap://server1 ldap://server2 does not work as well, it still contacts server1 and if it is offline, authentication fails.

Thank you, Martin

Comment: Did you get this working?  Do you have any more details like errors from the logs or anything?  Not sure if it is needed, but perhaps post some config excerpts.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is correct, are you sure the second server works correctly?

Comment: Ok, Debian lenny seems to retrieve this info from libnss-ldap.conf, so ldap.conf or pam_ldap.conf does not affects sshd.

Answer (score 0):

> **host server1  server2**

Is an alternative to your string posted above.
from my personal experience i have found that the Secondary Server would not work due to the fact that my authentication would timeout before it reached the Second Server.If ssh is used increase the ssh timeout.
or have the following in your ldap.conf

> nss_reconnect_tries 2
>   nss_reconnect_sleeptime 1
>   nss_reconnect_maxsleeptime 4
>   nss_reconnect_maxconntries 1